# Get number of twitter shares by url

Tags: php, twitter, network-shares

I have a question about twitter counting. Everything is so blury about this. 
Simply:
I have website with dynamic pages, button for tweet, people go to page, press tweet, it shows on they twitter, count on my page increase. but I need also on my backend to call to twitter and ask them how many shares i have already and count with that.

It is concept for voting. People by sharing to facebook and twitter are voting for the website, so i need to take those votes and count them together. Please dont recommend me scripts like "sharecount" i tried and it has a lot of issues, and its not reliable.
I can get easily likes from facebook but i dont seems to get how to get the number of shares from twitter.

Also if anyone can help me, is there a way to get shares from unique users ? I noticed that if i tweet the site 50 times, the counter is 50. I would like it to count 50 tweets from 1 user as 1.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the private API method `http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=`

Comment: Thanks for help, actually I have been forced to use sharecount, so i have to fight with that... But thanks for advice!

Comment: So it wasn't possible! and is it possible to get the count for a specific user? (i need to know how many times a specific user mentioned the site in order to give him site points)

Comment: FYI this is now deprecated and doesn't work anymore.